# Keep QTip Tooltips from going off screen? (Bound to body?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have QTips:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    element.qtip({
        content: event.title + event.hours,
        position:{
            target: 'mouse'
        },
        //  show: { event: 'click' },
        hide: { event: 'mousedown mouseleave' },
        style: { 
            width: 200,
            padding: 5,
            color: 'black',
            textAlign: 'left',
            border: {
                width: 1,
                radius: 3
            },
            classes: 'custSideTip'
        } 
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.custSideTip
{
    position:fixed !important;
    right:0 !important;
    max-width:200px !important;
}
```

[image]

But they go off the page...

I tried right and fixed position and nothing seems to work...

The right coordinate of the tip should never exceed the body.right / page.right... if that makes sense..

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [**here**](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-how-to-keep-qtip-from-drawing-off-screen).

You can try to use [**viewport**](http://qtip2.com/plugins#viewport) config:

```
position: { viewport: $(window) }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm glad this was an easy fix.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and other examples didn't with some error in jQuery code. Perhaps some version discrepancy?

```
position: { viewport: $(document.body) }
```